# SSO Authentication with Active Directory in iOS Apps

Tags: ios, active-directory, single-sign-on

I am asking this question second time since I didn't get a proper answer earlier.

Following are the steps to better explain my situation:

1. I'm creating a iOS app in an iPad for my organization.
2. I have a VPN connection through Junos Pulse in the iPad in order to
   be in the organization's network. Junos Pulse uses my ntid/password
   to establish a VPN connection in the iPad.
3. I want to implement SSO authentication with the Active Directory for
   my iOS app. I don't want to do it by calling a webservice which will authenticate with active directory. I want to have the user authenticated with the active directory in the iOS app itself.

Is there a way to accomplish this given the above scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Kerberos support on iOS, so a clear answer is *no*. You might want to search my answers. I have answered similar questions before.

Comment: Its added later and its available in iOS 13.0 as I type here.

Comment: @Prav, it has been added way earlier, but past the date of my answer.